# ¿Por qué hay error de sintaxis en éste arrow function?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy leyendo acerca de los [casos especiales](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html#_omitting-parentheses-around-single-parameters) de las `funciones flecha (arrow functions`) en javascript y me encontré con un ejemplo que no pude ejecutar.

El ejemplo es:

```
[[1,2], [3,4]].map(([a,b]) => a + b);
```

lo cual si lo tratamos de imprimir a la consola debería de darnos éste resultado:

```
console.log([[1,2], [3,4]].map(([a,b]) => a + b));

//[ 3, 7 ]  <== resultado
```

El problema es que al tratar de ejecutar esa línea, me aparece el siguiente error:

```
console.log([[1,2], [3,4]].map(([a,b]) => a + b));
                            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:1003:3
```

Estoy usando el modo estricto:

```
'use strict';
```

Las pruebas las he hecho con estas versiones de node (en OSX):

```
5.4.0
5.0.0
4.3.0
4.0.0
```

En todos los casos, el resultado ha sido el mismo, ¿por qué?

Comment: Yo lo pruebo en node v5.0 para Windows 7 y nunca termina de ejecutarlo.

Comment: Lo probé en `5.0.0` para OSX y el mismo error de sintaxis de arriba.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El motivo por el que puede no funcionar en alguna plataforma o navegador se debe a que la característica de ECMAScript 2015 [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment) que es la que permite la sintaxis para *"desarmar el array"* está todavía en proceso de desarrollo en algunas plataformas:

## Node.js

En Node.js *Destructuring assignment* está en fase experimental y deshabilitada por defecto.

Para poder habilitarla ejecutar Node con el flag `--harmony-destructuring`

Ejemplo:

```
node --harmony-destructuring script.js
```

## Chrome

En Chrome [*Destructuring* está activado por defecto desde la versión 49](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4588790303686656) por lo que el ejemplo debe correr sin problemas con la última versión de Chrome.

En versiones anteriores:

1. Navegar a `chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony`
2. Habilitar la característica
3. Reiniciar el navegador

## Edge

Edge lo implementa como características experimentales. Para poder activar el soporte:

1. Navegar a `about:flags`
2. Marcar el check *Características experimentales* --> *JavaScript* --> *Habilitar características de JavaScript experimentales*
3. Reiniciar el navegador

Comment: ¡Funciona! Qué genial :D

Comment: Pueden seguir editando y agregando más plataformas/navegadores si desean

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz perfecto, si puedes agregar más para convertir esta respuesta en una respuesta canónica sería de beneficio para la comunidad.